# Create New Document in Embedded Editor

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have an Account Form with  associated Contact Forms as Response Documents to the Account. I show the Contacts for the Account in an Embedded View and associated Embedded Editor in the Account Form. So highlighting a Contact in the Embedded View then allows me to edit and save a Contact in the Embedded Editor. All fine and as intended use. Is there a way of creating a new Contact document and displaying it instantly in the Embedded Editor. A button in the Account form will allow me to create the Contract, make it a response and it will display in the Embedded View as an empty document, but you then need to select it and edit it from the Embedded View, which is not very user friendly. I know I could pop up a dialog and partially fill the Contact info then re-select it from the Embedded View, again not very slick.  I need to click a button and the newly created doc to appear in the Embedded Editor and the Embedded View. Seems a basic requirement, but I can't think of a way to achieve it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks